# Which version of spring-security-core jar is compatible with Spring-core-4.1.9

Tags: java, spring

Which version of **Spring-security-core** jar is compatible with **Spring-core-4.1.9** ?

I am using Spring-core-4.1.9 in my application but bit confused which version of **Spring-security-core** jar should be used?

Comment: I think `spring-security-core-4.0.0-RELEASE` is the right Version for you. It is compatible with spring-core-4.1.6

Comment: The (current) latest version of Spring Security is 4.1.3. The [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) for that version mentions that it has been compiled with Spring Core 4.3.2. However, the documentation [also mentions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom) that 4.1.3 can be used with Spring versions as far back as 4.0. So,  version 4.1.9 should work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [4.1.x](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#get-spring-security) Spring security documentation, you should use 4.3.2.RELEASE of Spring core.